# TensorflowLite without pthreads

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is there a way to run tensorflow lite without pthreads?

[This post](https://medium.com/@tomasreimers/compiling-tensorflow-for-the-browser-f3387b8e1e1c) talks about disabling threading in tensorflow but I can not find a way to reproduce it in TensorflowLite.

Comment: Can you share a bit more about your build environment and any pthreads-related restrictions? Note that on Windows we do not use pthreads directly.